# How to return input + string if value doesn't exist in DB?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to query a table for an array with user names and I want to not only get the name and user ids if found but also if it wasn't found, I want a string.

I have the following query using Bigquery

```
SELECT
user_id,
name as user_name
FROM table
WHERE name IN ('userone', 'usertwo', 'userfourtysix')
```

Current Output

| user_ID | user_name |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | userone |
| 002 | usertwo |

Desire Output

| user_ID | user_name |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | userone |
| 002 | usertwo |
| NULL | userfourtysix |

or a string with input + 'doesn't exist'

Is that possible with SQL?

Comment: Your query is not valid SQL. Please add some input with the expected output to help understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in SQL but not with the IN clause, since you are filtering out any values that don't match with the IN clause.

You need to rewrite your query to take advantage of JOINS.

1. Create a CTE with the list of names you want to manage
2. Perform a left join so that values on the CTE are preserved even if there's no match in the right table.